# Use Un-Published bintray artifact

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I have recently uploaded an artifact to bintray using gradle. How can I use it using my username and api key without publishing to Maven Central?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add maven url to your top build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "http://dl.bintray.com/<your_bintray_account_name>/maven"
        }
}
```

Where, `<your_bintray_account_name>` is the handle you see in the url after login into Bintray -> `https://bintray.com/<your_bintray_account_name>/maven`